# Drawing triangles after calculating points in GLSL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have a task to prepare a hipsometric globe in OpenGL. Besides of the colours of the vertices, I need some vertices to be higher (mountains), some to be lower.

Currently, I have a program which generates a globe, only with points (every 1 degree), all on the same height, I am doing that by passing latitude ang longitude to my program in GLSL, and it calculates translation matrix for each vertex.

Now, I can easily imagine how to move vertices higher and lower - I will just add another uniform variable "height", and in GLSL I will do the rest. The same easy thing is with passing color - no problem.

However, I have no idea, how to create a whole map using triangles (well, quadrangles composed from two triangles).
The best solution I have, is that when I have four vertices (x1, x2, x3, x4) which create a quadrangle, I could just transform a quadrangle (which was previously in the buffer) in that way, to produce a quadrangle which has corners in my four vertices (x1, x2, x3, x4). Then, I just pass it to GLSL and render it.

However, I don't know how to transform a quadrangle to create a new quadrangle with corners in my vertices. Is it possible? Or maybe another idea how to realize this quadrangles?

**Additional info:**

I am using OpenGL 3.3.

This is how I render points:

```
for (double lng = 0; lng < 360; lng++) {
    for (double lat = 0; lat < 180; lat++) {
        draw_dots(MVP, lat, lng);
    }
}

// draw_dots function:
glUniform1f(latID, lat);
glUniform1f(lngID, lng);
glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, field1_location);
```

This is my vertex shader:

```
gl_Position = MVP * transl_mtx * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace, 1);
```

where transl_mtx is translation matrix calculated from uniform variables "lat" and "lng".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, nope, *nope*.

Thing about GPU rendering is usually the biggest performance hit is the CPU-GPU sync point. Thus you typically want to reduce the number of commands per frame to absolute minimum. The one and only function we can't  remove is a *draw call*; typically `glDrawElements` or `gDrawArrays`.

However, you're calling this function thousands of times each frame. Considering the fact that your GPU (most probably) has a few gigabytes a memory, here's a better solution:

1. Generate the whole set of vertices offline to a regular float array.
2. Copy that to a GPU via VBO.
3. Use `in` variable instead of a `uniform`, and only pass MVP matrix via uniform.
4. Use just one drawcall to render the whole model.

That way you can manipulate and prepare the data conveniently on a CPU *once*, and then use the absurd speed of GPU to draw it.

Comment: Ok, one more question. I also have to implement simple Level of Detail. Just by "skip every second/third vertex" to get less accurate but faster result.

If sync point is my bottleneck, it will be good idea to send whole package of new vertices each time when user change level of detail - because he will do it rarely, right?

Comment: @Świstak35 You tell me if he'll do it rarely `:)`. Considering LoD that are going with powers-of-two (1/2 of vertices, 1/4 of vertices, ...), you could actually create them *all* and just switch to the set you want, because the sum of memory taken [will be less than 2 times normal](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%2B+1%2F2+%2B+1%2F4+%2B+...).

Comment: @Świstak35 Or, alternatively, you could use a tesselation shader to do that for you, but I'm afraid it's kinda beyond the scope of this question to explain how it would work; still, you might want to know your options, I suppose.

Comment: Thank you very much. One last thing I want to ask. If I want to pass some other "vertex data", other than color and position - such as, in this example "height", I should do this by using another layout and `glVertexAttribPointer`, right? I was previously wondering about what are the usecases of another layouts, and I guess I finally found it `: )`.